JOLT for a optional nested NODE in JSON
I have a JSON from source and I am trying to write a JOLT to flatten this data and convert it in to records so that I can insert it in to a Table.
I have already written a JOLT by referring to my previous queries, but unbale to get desired output.
This question is different from Jolt to transform a multilayered Nested JSON to flat JSON because there the nesting is different and also it do not have optional nodes.
Input JSON
{
  "CustomerMaster": {
    "Rootnode": {
      "KUNNR": "0000028790",
      "NAME1": "NV Solucious",
      "LAND1": "BE",
      "SalesArea": [
        {
          "VKORG": "0200",
          "VTWEG": "00",
          "SPART": "00"
        },
        {
          "VKORG": "4932",
          "VTWEG": "00",
          "SPART": "00",
          "AUFSD1": "FT",
          "PartnerFunction": [
            {
              "PARVW": "ZP",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "0000028790"
            },
            {
              "PARVW": "ZS",
              "PARZA": "000",
              "KUNN2": "90010523"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "VKORG": "4932",
          "VTWEG": "10",
          "SPART": "00",
          "Indicator": {
            "IsDistributionCenter": "X"
          },
          "PartnerFunction": {
            "PARVW": "ZS",
            "PARZA": "000",
            "KUNN2": "90010523"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


Desired Output
[ {
  "KUNNR": "0000028790",
  "NAME1": "NV Solucious",
  "LAND1": "BE",,
  "VKORG": "0200",
  "VTWEG": "00",
  "SPART": "00",
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000028790",
  "NAME1" : "NV Solucious",
  "LAND1" : "BE",
  "VKORG" : "0200",
  "VTWEG" : "00",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "AUFSD1": "FT",
  "PARVW": "ZP",
  "PARZA": "000",
  "KUNN2": "0000028790"
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000028790",
  "NAME1" : "NV Solucious",
  "LAND1" : "BE",
  "VKORG" : "0200",
  "VTWEG" : "00",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "AUFSD1": "FT",
  "PARVW": "ZS",
  "PARZA": "000",
  "KUNN2": "90010523"
}, {
  "KUNNR" : "0000028790",
  "NAME1" : "NV Solucious",
  "LAND1" : "BE",
  "VKORG" : "4932",
  "VTWEG" : "10",
  "SPART" : "00",
  "IsDistributionCenter": "X",
  "PARVW": "ZS",
  "PARZA": "000",
  "KUNN2": "90010523"
}]

I am not getting desired output using the JOLT provided above and need your help to write a JOLT to get desired output.

Does this answer your question? Jolt to transform a multilayered Nested JSON to flat JSON

Hi @BarbarosÖzhan - I have used the base JOLT from the mentioned question and updated the JOLT, but after addition of new node "Indicator" in the JSON, I am unable to get desired output.

Modifying a above jolt provided by @LucaBiscotti and @BarbarosÖzhan little bit to handle all cases.
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "CustomerMaster": {
        "Rootnode": {
          "SalesArea": "=toList"
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "CustomerMaster": {
        "Rootnode": {
          "SalesArea": {
            "*": {
              "PartnerFunction": "=toList"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "CustomerMaster": {
        "Rootnode": {
          "*": "else1.&",
          "SalesArea": {
            "*": {
              "*": "&1.else2.&",
              "Indicator": { //Added the indicator field
                "*": "&2.else2.&"
              },
              "PartnerFunction": {
                "*": {
                  "*": "&3.&2[&1].&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "PartnerFunction|*": {
          "*": {
            "@(3,else1)": { "*": "&4[&1].&" },
            "@(2,else2)": { "*": "&4[&1].&" },
            "*": "&3[&1].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the outermost keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]


The answer provided by @BarbarosÖzhan in Jolt to transform a multilayered Nested JSON to flat JSON is nearly perfect; it only misses a small detail for the "Indicator" field.
Here is the completed Jolt (I only added a few rows):
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "CustomerMaster": {
        "Rootnode": {
          "*": "else1.&",
          "SalesArea": {
            "*": {
              "*": "&1.else2.&",
              "Indicator": {       //Added the indicator field
                "*": "&2.else2.&"
              },
              "PartnerFunction": {
                "*": {
                  "*": "&3.&2[&1].&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "PartnerFunction": {
          "*": {
            "@(3,else1)": { "*": "&4[&1].&" },
            "@(2,else2)": { "*": "&4[&1].&" },
            "*": "&3[&1].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the outermost keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]


Hi @BarbarosÖzhan - Node Indicator and PartnerFunction are optional and may not occur in all JSON, so I am unable to read some JSON's correctly. I updated the JSON in my question with this scenario.

Hi @LucaBiscotti - Node Indicator and PartnerFunction are optional and may not occur in all JSON, so I am unable to read some JSON's correctly. I updated the JSON in my question with this scenario.

Hi @JasonMoore , are you sure that the PartnerFunction isn't always an array? Even if it only has one element.

Hi @LucaBiscotti , Yes PartnerFunction will not be a array but it is optional and the element inside it - IsDistributionCenter and IsPlanAccount are also optional. Node PartnerFunction can be a array and this node is also optional.
